# "To know all about something" vs. "a know-all"

Tags: word-choice

The *Oxford Thesaurus of English* says that the noun *know-all* is
informal. For example, when saying:

> You are such a know-all.

My concern is with using *know all* as a combination of the verb
*to know + all*. Example:

> People today *know all* about technology-use.

Is doing this informal or conversational in this sentences, because
we can have more formal alternatives such as more knowledgeable,
more experienced, more familiar, and so on and so forth?

Comment: **know all** is not a verb.  **know** is a verb; **all** is the object of the verb.  _People today know._  What do they know?  _People today know **all about technology**._

Comment: @Roger Sinasohn Yes of course! I meant adding 'all' to the verb 'to know' making it 'to know all' and since a 'know-all' as a noun is informal,  I am wondering if the combination 'to know all' would also be informal!

Comment: But _all_ **isn't** added to the verb.  Consider this:  _People know about technology._  How much do they know about it?  _People know **all** about technology._  **All** describes how much they know about technology.  It has nothing to do with the verb.  Even without the tech bit, _I know all_ is a simple sentence with a subject (I), verb (know), and object (all).  It could be _I know Bobby_ or _I know French_ or _I know a secret_ and it's all the same.

Comment: I think saying someone knows "all" about something is rather informal/conversational, assuming they don't literally know everything there is to know about the given topic.  You might want to say something like, "people today know a lot about technology use," or "people today tend to be well informed about technology."

Comment: The noun ***know-all*** (or ***know-it-all*** as is more common around here) is an informal term because it's a mashup of two (or three) words to describe someone in a less than flattering way.  A formal version would be ***subject matter expert*** (or just ***expert***).

Comment: So, to sum up, if you want to say _people today know all about technology use_, that's perfectly find in both an informal/conversational or formal situation.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn - Three Comments combine to be worthy of an Answer, for the patience of a saint.

Comment: Note that know-it-alls are not so much experts as a**holes, in lording their large or small store of knowledge above others: "Ha, don't you know that's patently absurd!" Experts know they do not know it all, and they do not brag. Know-it-alls are bullies who have to be right.

Answer (score 1):

**Know-it-all** or **know-all** is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know-it-all) which occasionally used in a positive sense to indicate that the person is indeed a wealth of knowledge, but is most often used in the sense that the individual *thinks* he's an expert on everything and will, if permitted, spend hours bending your ear to explain how he's right and you're wrong.

To "know all about" a topic is generally a literal statement (though perhaps a hair hyperbolic) -- the individual is an expert on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

In the example sentence

> People today know all about technology use.

*Know all* is *not* a verb.  *Know* is the verb here; *all* is part of the *object* of the verb.

> People today know.
>   What do they know?
>   People today know *all about technology*.

Note that *all* isn't being added to the verb. It is a modifier of the object.  Consider this:

> People know about technology.
>   How much do they know about it?
>   People know *all* about technology.

All describes how much they know about technology. It has nothing to do with the verb. Even without the tech bit, *I know all* is a simple (but valid) sentence with a subject (I), verb (know), and object (all). It could be *I know Bobby* or *I know French* or *I know a secret* and it's all the same: *I know [something]*.  In this case, it's *I know [all about technology].*

Meanwhile...

The noun *know-all* (or *know-it-all* as is more common around here) is
an informal term because it's a mashup of two (or three) words to describe
someone in a less than flattering way. A formal version (without the
sarcasm that goes along with *know-it-all*) would be *subject matter
expert* (or just *expert*).

So, to sum up, if you want to say *people today know all about technology
use*, that's perfectly fine in both an informal/conversational or formal
situation.  If you want to acknowledge that someone knows what they're
talking about in a more formal setting (without being derogatory), I
wouldn't use *know-it-all*.

Comment: The answer is generally correct, but "know-it-all" is not slang for "expert." Not only is "know-it-all" derogatory, but it does not necessarily concede that the person being described does in fact have the degree of knowledge claimed.